# Excel macro "Run-time error '1004"

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to scripting and I am trying to improve a existing Macro. 
I recorded a macro to remove dupliate and added it in a Main function which calls some other functions, but I am getting this error when I add the macro I recorded:
Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error.

The code looks like

```
Sub Main()
Call DuplicateRemove
Call DeleteBlankRows
Call TrimText
End 

Sub DeleteBlankRows()
.
.
End Sub

Sub TrimText()
.
.
End Sub

Sub DuplicateRemove()
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$95678").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: On which line/routine are you getting the error?

Comment: I am getting the error only when I add the macro I recorded:   Sub DuplicateRemove()
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$95678").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub

Comment: Does `Sub TrimText()
.
.
` imply that you actually have the words `End Sub` somewhere in there?

Comment: "'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error." effectively means that you have an unhandled error in your VBA code.  Add error-handling with MSGBOX statements to see what the actual VBA error is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You will only get this error if the `Active` worksheet is password protected.

Also it is a much better option to avoid using `.Select` and `ActiveSheet`. Your code can be written as

```
Sub DuplicateRemove()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        If .ProtectContents = True Then
            MsgBox "Worksheet is protected"
            .Unprotect "MYPASSWORD"
            .Range("$A$1:$A$95678").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
            .Protect "MYPASSWORD"
        Else
            .Range("$A$1:$A$95678").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

```
Sub DuplicateTest()
    ActiveSheet.Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Siddharth, but the worksheet is not password protected.

Comment: you want me to send the file?

Comment: You can upload the file in www.wikisend.com and then share the link here?

Comment: That is an Excel 2003 file. Which Excel version do you have?

Comment: Excel 2010, you think this is causing the issue?

Comment: No. I thought that you have Excel 2003 :) I have updated the code above.

Comment: It worked perfectly, Thanks Siddarth and can you also take a look at my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727620/clear-contents-of-a-worksheet-using-macro-without-clearing-the-clipboard

Comment: Gr8 :) Answered in that question.

Answer (score 1):

This error occur if The Microsoft Visual Basic Applications copies and pastes whole row in an Excel 2003 workbook or this error may be occur if the Microsoft copies and pastes a range of 2,516 rows or more rows in an Excel 2003 workbook at this cases  [runtime error](http://www.runtimehelp.com) 1004 occurs.
To get solution of this error save the workbook and manipulate the code of the macro in which you can save workbook.

Answer (score -1):

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1,2), Header:=xlYes

Here is info I found about your situation, I hope it is helpful.