# Run-Time error '1004' The specified value is out of range

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

```
Sub FindInShapes1()   
Dim rStart As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sFind As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim Response

sFind = InputBox("Search for?")
If Trim(sFind) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Nothing entered"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set rStart = ActiveCell
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
    If InStr(LCase(sTemp), LCase(sFind)) <> 0 Then
        shp.Select
        Response = MsgBox( _
          prompt:=shp.TopLeftCell & vbCrLf & _
          sTemp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "Do you want to continue?", _
          Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Continue?")
        If Response <> vbYes Then
            Set rStart = Nothing
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next
MsgBox "No more found"
rStart.Select
Set rStart = Nothing
End Sub
```

Hi,

I made the above Macro for finding excel shapes in a "crouded" worksheet, by the text written inside. The macro works in any new books but not in the one I need, were it keeps on showing the following message:

```
"Run-Time error '1004'
The specified value is out of range"
```

and as soon as i click on "Debug" it highlights the line:

```
sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text
```

What's wrong?

Thanks for your help
Chiara

Comment: the error `1004` is a kind of catch all, so doesn't really point to the actual problem. What you could do is put a breakpoint (using F9) on the line `sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text` then keep pressing F5 until you get the error. This would tell you which Shape object is causing the problem - it may well be that it is the very first one, and that your code isn't handling the error - such as maybe there is no text in the shape object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think as there is no way to check for the existence of a **TextFrame** within a shape, you should ignore the error by using *On Error Resume Next*:

```
Sub FindInShapes1()
Dim rStart As Range
Dim shp As Shape
Dim sFind As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim Response

On Error Resume Next

sFind = InputBox("Search for?")
If Trim(sFind) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Nothing entered"
    Exit Sub
    End If
    Set rStart = ActiveCell
    For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        'If shp.TextFrame.Characters.Count > 0 Then
        If InStr(LCase(sTemp), LCase(sFind)) <> 0 Then
            shp.Select
            Response = MsgBox( _
                prompt:=shp.TopLeftCell & vbCrLf & _
                sTemp & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                "Do you want to continue?", _
                Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Continue?")
            If Response <> vbYes Then
                Set rStart = Nothing
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        'End If
        sTemp = shp.TextFrame.Characters.Text

    Next
    MsgBox "No more found"
    rStart.Select
    Set rStart = Nothing
End Sub
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to break the convention but the similar error I get:

```
The specified value is out of range
Run-time error -2147024809
```

In my scenario I am simply returning a shape as part of a GET property in side a class that store a Shape Object. The property works for Shape Type Text Boxes but craps out on sending back Line Shapes. As per below.
I cannot use the on error, Or don't know how because the error occur at End Property?

```
Public Property Get shp_Obj() As Shape
    If prvt_int_Ordinal = 13 Them

        MsgBox prvt_Shp_Shape.Name, , "prvt_Shp_Shape.Name"



    Set shp_Obj = prvt_Shp_Shape
   End If

End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. You will only get this error if the Active worksheet is password protected.

Can you check that?

Also check below url from so

[Excel macro "Run-time error '1004"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746478/excel-macro-run-time-error-1004)

Comment: How can I check that? I mean, the file I want the macro to work with is a shared file but I'm allowed to read and write on it!

Comment: I didn't get that error, without `On Error` (bad coding I know) I got a **Type Mismatch**

Comment: Great!!!!!! With On Error Resume the macro works!!!! thank you Philip your help has been crucial! ;-)

Comment: @ChiaraCiani: Thanks, it's not the ideal solution, but the best I could think of without being able to check for a TextFrame!

Comment: Hi Philip...it's me again! The macro had no problem so far... today it started doing something weird: when I enter text in the search area it shows the right cell references and then, when you select "continue", it finds wrong cell references... where the shape absolutely there isn't!!!! HELP ME!!! what can be changed???

Comment: After several tests i probably figured out the matter but I din't find a solution! Connected to some shapes there are arrows. Is in this case that the problem occurs indeed! What could I write in the code to neglect this exceptions? Thanks!!!