# Using VBA in PowerPoint to change font

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I use VBA to make the font consistent throughout a PowerPoint presentation?

I'm new to VBA, so the code I used could be completely wrong but here it is:

```
Sub FontChange()

  Dim sld As Slide
  Dim shp As Shape

   For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
       For Each shp In sld.Shapes
       shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font

         .Size = 12

         .Name = "Bauhaus 93"

         .Bold = False

         .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)
    Next shp
   Next sld
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What's happening when you run it?  you don't really explain the problem you are having. Looks like you need a `with` and `end with` statement.

Comment: It highlights "TextFrame" and says "Method or data member not found"

Comment: `Sub Font()

        With ActivePresentation

          With .TextFrame.TextRange.Font

            .Size = 48

            .Name = "Bauhaus 93"

            .Bold = True

             .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)

              End With
 
        End With
    End Sub`

Comment: ^ the above code using `with` and `end with` had the same issue as well.

Comment: What "same issues" ?  What error are you getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few mods to Wayne's version in the event that you want to change text that's not in placeholders. And a few tests to make sure that the shape in question a) CAN contain text (shapes like lines cannot) and if so b) that it HAS some text to modify.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FontChange()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then  ' Not all shapes do
    If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then  ' the shape may contain no text
        With shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
            .Size = 12
            .Name = "Bauhaus 93"
            .Bold = False
            .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)
        End With
    End If
    End If
    Next shp
Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below should work. Note that your original didn't test the 'Type' of shape, or as @Tim pointed out, you were missing the 'With ...'

Also, my test of a text shape had a Type of 14, which is a 'placeholder'. You may need to check for additional types if the code doesn't change some fonts you want changed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FontChange()

Dim sld As Slide
Dim shp As Shape

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        With shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
            .Size = 12
            .Name = "Bauhaus 93"
            .Bold = False
            .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 127, 255)
        End With
    End If
    Next shp
Next sld
```

End Sub

Comment: when I ran the code this time, it says "the specified value is out of range" then highlights the line "With shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Font". Any ideas? I also don't know what you mean with the Type 14 and placeholder stuff - could you please explain? Sorry, I just was introduced to VBA today so don't really know terms yet.

Comment: Did you copy and paste my entire code (plus the darn 'End Sub' that fell outside)? If not, then you must either do that or show the EXACT code you are now trying to use. Re the 'Type 14' comment, your code was looping through EVERY control on the slide - not just text -- so some 'shapes' may not have a 'Text' property. In the line 'If shp.Type = msoPlaceholder Then' that is checking the shape type for a type of 14 (which equates to msoPlaceholder). Possibly there are other shape types that have a font you want to change, which means you need to also check for those types as well.

Comment: I did copy and paste the entire code (including the 'End Sub' that fell outside). The deck which I am using right now has not special shapes. It's just 4 white slides with 3 random sentences on each slide. I wanted to keep it super simple right now as I test out different codes. But thank you for explaining the Type comment - that will definitely be useful as I progress.

Comment: Based upon another post I found (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715951/run-time-error-1004-the-specified-value-is-out-of-range) you can try inserting line "On Error Resume Next" just before the "With..." and see what happens. I will keep looking... Is there only one shape on the slide? That can cause it...