# Check if a property of an object has value or not

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I couldn't find a solution for this on SO or other source. I apologize in advance if this is a tired question:

I have a macro that iterates through placeholders in shapes. Some of these placeholders have text, some don't. I'm trying to figure out if 
`.Shapes.Placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange` has any value or not (In the 'watches' section of the VBA editor, this property has `<The specified value is out of range.>`). If it does, do something. Otherwise, continue the `For Each` statement. However, everything I tried has thrown out of bounds errors or something of that type.

I have tried:

- `If Not (placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange.Length = 0) Then`: Immediately throws out of bounds error
- Try/catch, which doesn't seem to exist in VBA (Gives me Sub or Function not registered)
- `If Not CStr(placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange) = "0" then`

I'm quite out of my depth as I don't have experience with any Visual Basic iteration. I just need to, if that property is empty or null, skip over the placeholder.

EDIT: Following suggestions, I tried this:

```
For Each placeholder In sld.NotesPage.Shapes.Placeholders
    If Not (placeholder.TextFrame Is Nothing) Then
        If Not (placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange Is Nothing) Then
            If Not (placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID Is Nothing) Then
                placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange.LanguageID = lng
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I still get an out of bounds error on `placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange Is Nothing`. Did I make a syntax error?

**FINAL EDIT:** Turns out there was an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715951/run-time-error-1004-the-specified-value-is-out-of-range) in SO after all. For this specific problem, it was enough to add `On Error Resume Next` right after the`For Each`.

Comment: Don't chain your member accesses like that (this is why).  You need to check whether each relevant intermediary object is `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks Comintern. I did that, but I still get an out of bounds error when it reaches the TextRange if. I tried with `Is Nothing` and `Is Empty`

Comment: VBA doesn't have an inline null check operator like  `“?.”`.  The best you get is `IS Nothing`, so you can start checking step by step like If Not Parent Is Nothing Then ... If Not Child Is Nothing then ......

Comment: I updated the question with the code I tried. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: I'm not horribly familiar with the PPT object model, but have you checked in the Object Browser to see if the `Shapes` collection return objects with more specific interfaces you could test for?

Comment: I can't understand why you'd get an Out of Bounds error on that line of code. You might try to test whether `placeholder.TextFrame.HasText` instead of `placeholder.TextFrame.TextRange Is Nothing`?

Comment: When testing to see if a shape has text, assuming a shape reference in the variable oSh for demo purposes, first test: If oSh.HasTextFrame (some shapes, lines for example, don't). Then test If oSh.TextFrame.HasText