# Out of range error when drawing a line shape in Excel

Tags: excel, vb.net

This is a bizarre error I am facing in excel while drawing a line. I am using the below code

```
Sub DrawLine( )
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
     Set s = ws.Shapes.AddLine(100, 10, 100, 170000)
    s.Line.DashStyle = msoLineDash
    s.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = msoArrowheadStealth
End Sub
```

The error I am getting is Index is out of range. I then modified the value of 170000 to 5000 and it works perfectly. It seems like Excel has a limit on the height of the line. Can someone please clarify if that's true and what is the other way around to draw line shape of this height?

Comment: Would you say 170 000 is a reasonable / valid x/y position?

Comment: yes it is, i need to draw a line from cell D2 to D20000, when you convert that to px, its around 170000

Comment: Some bizarre suggestions here you could try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715951/run-time-error-1004-the-specified-value-is-out-of-range

Comment: i checked and that is not related to my question

Comment: In my testing, it seems that `169066` works, whereas `169067` fails.

Comment: As a workaround, try `s = ws.Shapes.AddLine(100, 10, 100, 169066)` and  `s.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoArrowheadStyle.msoArrowheadNone`. Then add another shape: `s1 = ws.Shapes.AddLine(100, 169066, 100, 170000)` and `s1.Line.EndArrowheadStyle = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoArrowheadStyle.msoArrowheadStealth`

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing now as a workaround, is there a way we can group the next created line ?